# How to give parameter when calling a page with $.get in Ionic?

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I'm working on a web-app with ionic.
On one of my pages i have a div-tag on which i'm loading another html-page.
I do this in controllers.js with the following code:

```
    var panel_dynamic = document.getElementById('panel_dynamic');
    if (panel_dynamic.hasChildNodes()) {
        panel_dynamic.removeChild(panel_dynamic.childNodes[0]);
    }
    var line = document.createElement("div");
    if(item.id == 9999)
    {
        $.get("templates\\type-of-test.html", function (response) {
            line.innerHTML = response;
        });
        panel_dynamic.appendChild(line);
    }
```

Can i give parameters to type-of-test.html using $.get?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Append your template URL with "?" and parameter like :

```
 $.get("templates\\type-of-test.html?Param=yourParam", function (response) {
```

and in controller of the template you can use $state to access your url parameter

```
$scope.state = $state;
$scope.state.current.templateUrl.split("=")[1]; 
// output should be "yourParam"
```

Not an ideal way but will do the job. You can directly split the string by "?" and send parameter directly, but separating name and value of parameter and  is easy to read and understand.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now i have another Problem. How can i link the Controller with the page "type-of-test"? Normally i'm doing that in app.js by the state. But in this case i don't call the page by the state.

Comment: add ng-controller = "yourcontroller" in your html tag of template

Comment: Hi. I added the name of the controller in the first tag of the HTML-page and set a breakpoint in the code of the controller. The page is loaded inside the div on the other page, but 'm not getting to the breakpoint. The tag is: <ion-view view-title="Type of test" ng-controller="TypeOfTestCtrl">

Comment: did you get any error ? and did you imported the controller in index.html?

Comment: No i get no error. It's seems to be that the HTML-page has no reference to the controller in the script file controllers.js. And controllers.js itself is referenced in index.html: <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>